# Why when I use SKSpriteNode with an image it doesn't bounce but when I use SKShapeNode it does work?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am very new to Swift and I am trying to create a ball that bounces up and down. When I use:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Ball {
    let movingObject: SKShapeNode

    init() {
        movingObject = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25)
        movingObject.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
        movingObject.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        movingObject.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        movingObject.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

    }
}
```

it works fine. However, when I try to use an image, it doesn't bounce.

```
class Ball {
    let movingObject: SKSpriteNode
    let picture: String

    init(picture: String) {
        self.picture = picture
        movingObject = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: picture)
        movingObject.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: movingObject.size.width * 0.5)
        movingObject.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        movingObject.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        movingObject.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0

    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to be more meaningful. It should describe the actual problem or question you're asking (*this code doesn't work* is not a problem description that is useful). Your title should be clear enough to have meaning to future readers who see it in a search result. (Imagine searching for a problem and finding 100 questions whose titles are all variations of *this code does not work*; would that be useful to you without having to read through all 100 posts to see if one applies to you?)

Comment: Also please show the code that "works" and the code that "doesn't work". Be clear in what the problem is.

Comment: Debug and see what `movingObject.size.width` is turning out to be...

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between your two physics bodies is the radius. Therefore, this has to be the problem.

Try setting the radius to `25` like you did with the shape node to confirm, then try to reason about why `movingObject.size.width * 0.5` isn't coming out to a reasonable value. You can set a breakpoint and use the debugger to `print movingObject.size` to help.

Answer (score 1):

**About the `SKSpriteNode` sources:**

```
/**
     Initialize a sprite with an image from your app bundle (An SKTexture is created for the image and set on the sprite. Its size is set to the SKTexture's pixel width/height)
     The position of the sprite is (0, 0) and the texture anchored at (0.5, 0.5), so that it is offset by half the width and half the height.
     Thus the sprite has the texture centered about the position. If you wish to have the texture anchored at a different offset set the anchorPoint to another pair of values in the interval from 0.0 up to and including 1.0.
     @param name the name or path of the image to load.
     */
    public convenience init(imageNamed name: String)
```

In the first case you use 25 as radius, in the next you must check if movingObject.size.width` * 0.5 is a valid measure.

When you are in debug phases try to help yourself by turning on the `showsPhysics` property:

**Code of example**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsPhysics = true
            ...
        }
}
```

You can easily view the physicBody boundaries of your objects and you can notice it immediately if something is wrong.

[image]